# Missing parts on X11 forwarding

Tags: ssh, xorg, xserver

I use X11 forwarding to a server by `ssh -X my_server`. All works fine but there is a part on the screen not displayed. The mouse works there.

So it looks like this:

[image]

If I connect to another server it looks like this:

[image]

So the frame of the treeview is shown but not the content (scrollbar either).

By using `ssh -Y` its the same problem.

Comment: You are not connecting to another server, but another server is connecting to your local host X server. So the problem is your local host X-Server, which misses some elements, which are used by the client. You should read about how X-server works. You might try to make sure that your local host X-server has the same graphic libraries as your client. For Example, if your client uses QT 6.2, make sure your local host X-server has also latest QT 6.2 libraries.